# Can't select Instagram all post elements as the previously loaded post elements are being removed from the DOM along with the scrolling down

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, instagram, infinite-scroll

I am trying to create an Instagram scraping bot that collects all post-related information for a particular account using Python and Selenium. To do this, I think at first I select all post elements using driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="_aabd _aa8k  _al3l"]'), then I collect the required data from each of these post elements through iteration. To do so, I think to Keep scrolling till the end and select all post elements when they are loaded.
But I realize, the previously loaded post elements are being removed from the DOM along with the scrolling down, and this "driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="_aabd _aa8k  _al3l"]')" can not select all post elements. [Here is the Image of number of selected Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FnII.jpg)

please help me by giving a possible solution to load all elements and select them all at once.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.